# css opacity in IE

Tags: css, opacity

How to set opacity or filter in Smooth Navigational Menu for transperancy in submenu background in IE?

when i set ddsmoothmenu.css as

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    background: #0a449e;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter :alpha(opacity=90);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

its woeking in chrome and FF but submenus are not displaying in IE. Why? Plss give the solution, if anybody knows..........

Comment: If you haven't know this already, http://doctype.com is dedicated for web development related questions. You would get better answers from the experts there.

Comment: Do the submenus display in IE if you remove the references to opacity?

Answer (score 0):

I've found filter: alpha(opacity=n) gives mixed results in IE.  When it doesn't work, I'll use the following in an IE only stylesheet to get the same effect:

**IE only CSS:**

```
.ddsmoothmenu ul li {
    background: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='trans-bg.png',sizingMethod='scale');

}
```

In the above, trans-bg.png is a transparent .png that is equivalent to the colour #0a449e at 90% opacity.